# How to process a JSON using Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I passing a JSON string (inputJson) to my java code (PPProgramAddView) on the server side.

```
PPProgramAddView:
inputJson: [{"ppl_row":0,"ppl_time":"07:00","ppat_id":"Mw==","ppa_id":"MTI=","ppl_LeadAssist":"Lead"},{"ppl_row":1,"ppl_time":"07:10","ppat_id":"Mg==","ppa_id":"NA==","ppl_LeadAssist":"Assist"}]
```

When I try to process it I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ppl_row" (class client.Profile14), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "plTime", "plActivity", "plActivityType", "plRow", "plLeadAssist"])
 at [Source: (String)"[{"ppl_row":0,"ppl_time":"07:00","ppat_id":"Mw==","ppa_id":"MTI=","ppl_LeadAssist":"Lead"},{"ppl_row":1,"ppl_time":"07:10","ppat_id":"Mg==","ppa_id":"NA==","ppl_LeadAssist":"Assist"}]"; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]->client.Profile14["ppl_row"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
```

I have done a search and I can not find '"plTime", "plActivity", "plActivityType", "plRow", "plLeadAssist"' anywhere.

My code is:

```
//Look through the new program lines and add them.
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            
            Profile14[] profiles14 = mapper.readValue(inputJson, Profile14[].class);
          
            for (final Profile14 programLine : profiles14) {
              
                String ppl_row = programLine.getplRow();
                
                String ppl_time = null;
                if (programLine.getplTime().length() < 1){
                    ppl_time = "00:01";
                }else{
                    ppl_time = programLine.getplTime();
                }
                
                String ppat_id_encoded = programLine.getplActivityType();
                String ppa_id_encoded = programLine.getplActivity();
                String ppl_LeadAssist = programLine.getplLeadAssist().substring(0, Math.min(programLine.getplLeadAssist().length(), 45));
                
                byte[] valueDecoded3 = Base64.decodeBase64(ppat_id_encoded);//decoding part
                String ppat_id = new String(valueDecoded3);
                
                byte[] valueDecoded4 = Base64.decodeBase64(ppa_id_encoded);//decoding part
                String ppa_id = new String(valueDecoded4);
                
                System.out.println("ppID: " + ppID + " ppat_id: " + ppat_id + " ppa_id: " + ppa_id +
                    " ppl_row : " + ppl_row + " ppl_time: " + ppl_time + " ppl_LeadAssist: " + ppl_LeadAssist);

                MySQLConnection.addPPProgramLine(ppID, ppat_id, ppa_id, ppl_row, ppl_time, ppl_LeadAssist);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Error.");
        }
    }
}

class Profile14 {
    private String ppl_row;
    private String ppl_time;
    private String ppat_id;
    private String ppa_id;
    private String ppl_LeadAssist;
    
    public String getplRow() {
        return ppl_row;
    }
    public void setplRow(String ppl_row) {
        this.ppl_row = ppl_row;
    }
    
    public String getplTime() {
        return ppl_time;
    }
    public void setplTime(String ppl_time) {
        this.ppl_time = ppl_time;
    }
    
    public String getplActivityType() {
        return ppat_id;
    }
    public void setplActivityType (String ppat_id) {
        this.ppat_id = ppat_id;
    }
    
    public String getplActivity() {
        return ppa_id;
    }
    public void setplActivity(String ppa_id) {
        this.ppa_id = ppa_id;
    }
    
    public String getplLeadAssist() {
        return ppl_LeadAssist;
    }
    public void setplLeadAssist(String ppl_LeadAssist) {
        this.ppl_LeadAssist = ppl_LeadAssist;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profile14 [ppl_row=" + ppl_row + ", ppl_time=" + ppl_time + ", ppat_id=" + ppat_id
                + ", ppa_id=" + ppa_id + ", ppl_LeadAssist=" + ppl_LeadAssist + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't following JavaBean standards, and without explicit instructions Jackson doesn't know how to map your class.

The Java convention is to name properties like `pplRow`, and your JSON is using the alternate Ruby style of `ppl_row`. There are three options:

- Switch the entire Jackson engine to use an alternate style. (Not a great idea since it tends to cause collisions.
- Tell Jackson to use an alternate style for particular Java classes. (We'll do this.)
- Annotate each property with `@JsonProperty` (works, but lots of extra effort).

Start by using standard Java naming for your properties:

```
class Profile14 {
  private String pplRow;

  public String getPplRow() {
    return this.pplRow;
  }

  public void setPplRow(String s) {
    this.pplRow = s;
  }
}
```

Note that the naming *of the methods* is what defines the properties (since the backing field is private and technically doesn't have to exist). Your existing properties both don't match the names (`pl` instead of `ppl`) and don't have the proper capitalization.

Now add this annotation to your class:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

This tells Jackson to use `snake_case` for naming all of the properties. This should be enough to get your mapping working.